# iOS 6 Passbook: Open Passbook app from my app

Tags: iphone, ios6, passbook

I am building an application related to the Passbook app. Basically I am generating a boarding pass for a flight ticket and adding it to Passbook. That part is working fine. But, I want to open the Passbook app from my app to see the pass details.

I have seen that Apple has removed the URL scheme options. How can I achieve this?

Comment: iOS 6 is still under NDA please post on the developer forums

Comment: Thanks shabzco. Could i open contact app from my app?is it possible?

Comment: The question (if still valid) can be reopened as the NDA has been dropped yesterday.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, it worked well with the emulator but crashed on the device.
1 - Double check the Entitlements
2 - I used this when the _pass is already in the library:

```
if([_passLibrary containsPass:_pass])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[[_passLibrary passWithPassTypeIdentifier:[_pass passTypeIdentifier] serialNumber:[_pass serialNumber]] passURL]];        
}
```

Use the same context to delete the pass too:

```
[_passLibrary removePass: [_passLibrary passWithPassTypeIdentifier:[_pass passTypeIdentifier] serialNumber:[_pass serialNumber]]];
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: The answer posed seems to fail when the passes get grouped together and you have to swipe to go from one to the other. In this case openURL opens up the pass group and chooses one of them to show (whether or not it's the actual pass requested). Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: I filled a bug report about it and I will let you know if something happens.

Comment: I have the same issue as John Dota - I have a list of passes in my app with a "view in passbook" button for each and I want to be able to jump that particular pass in my group in Passbook when the user taps on the "view in passbook" button.

Comment: Share rdar number, so when submitting it the bug again and reference your ticket - this way bugs can gets fixed sooner by Apple.