# What is PassBook's URLScheme (for ios6)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, passbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS 6 Passbook: Open Passbook app from my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136914/ios-6-passbook-open-passbook-app-from-my-app)

Hi what is the URLScheme for the new passbook app in IOS6 as i can't find it anywhere on the web. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, this is opening Passbook. That is changing passbook details.

Comment: They probably aren't very familiar with the passbook standards. I agree that it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: thank you! at least someone know what they are talking about

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi I've just found the answer

It's 'shoebox' so in XCode you would implement:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"shoebox://"]];
```

Comment: You're right. You can also test this in Safari.app by just entering `shoebox://` in the address bar and then opening the URL

Answer (score 1):

There is no URL schemes provided for the Passbook application till now (January 1st 2013).

I saw a similar thread on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136914/ios-6-passbook-open-passbook-app-from-my-app), please check that too.